# Язык С. Написать функцию нахождения в массиве целых чисел элемента, ближайшего к значению второго аргумента типа int

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, функции

Изучаю язык С и работу с алгоритмами, массивами. Затрудняюсь придумать алгоритм, который будет корректно работать как с положительными и отрицательными целыми числами.

Важные штуки для понимания:

1. допустим тренировочное число exp = -10. Ввожу в массив 0 2 -9 -11. Алгоритм должен вывести -9 -11,т.к. ближайшие к exp. **Но выводить он может как 2 ближайших, если они одинаково близки, так и одно, или само значение exp, если оно задано в массиве.**
2. Разрешено использовать только функции printf, scanf_s, getchar (считывание символа с клавиатуры)!
3. Сам алгоритм должен быть описан в get_array(), выведен через main

Буду благодарен за помощь!

*P.S. Пишите только если знаете как помочь, без сторонних упрёков типа «думай сам» или «код говно», я застрял как бы)*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4 

int get_array(int* array, int len) // функция
{
    int exp = -10;
    int i = 0;
    // место для алгоритма
    return 0;
}

int main() // тестирующая программа
{
    int array[N];
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%i]=", i);
        scanf_s("%i", &array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
    s = get_array(array, N);
    return 0;
}
```

в месте для алгоритма пытался реализовать вычитание exp из каждого элемента массива, но тогда выводит только первое попавшееся близкое значение

```
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = array[0] - exp;
    int temp3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp = array[i] - exp;
        if (temp > 0)
        {
            if (temp <= temp2)
            {
                temp2 = temp;
                temp3 = array[i];
                printf("%d\n", temp3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp >= temp2)
            {
                temp2 = temp;
                temp3 = array[i];
                printf("%d\n", temp3);
            }
        }
    }
    return temp3;
```

Comment: а ты не путаешься во всех этих temp, temp2? Что такое temp2? Чем отличается от temp3? Попробуй давать переменным понятные имена.

Comment: Тебе нужно сначала НАЙТИ близкие значения, а потом уже их выводить. А ты почти в каждой итерации что-нибудь выводишь.

Comment: У вас нечеткая постановка. Например, *Но выводить он может как 2 ближайших, если они одинаково близки, так и одно, или само значение exp, если оно задано в массиве.* — так что нужно? Выводить два значения или одно? Далее, можно ли менять сам массив? А действовать можно очень просто, если для вывода один элемент. Поочередно вычитаем из каждого элемента массива искомый и ищем минимальное абсолютное значение...

Comment: @Harry, ... а найдя его, выводим все значения из массива, которые ему соответствуют. Так?

Comment: Код у вас плох, потому что вы его пишите не решив сперва задачу. Вы сами для себя понимаете какие числа выводить?

Comment: Уберите P.S.. Три четверти тех кто хочет вам помочь, перешли к следующему вопросу. Вежливость - необходимый элемент общения.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Зачем? Вроде же допускается выводить только одно значение?

Comment: @Harry, очень много плясок вокруг числа выводимых значений вместо "выведите любое ближайшее". Полагаю, корректная формулировка "выведите все ближайшие".

Comment: Да как обычно, при плохом ТЗ результат всегда ХЗ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если достаточно вывести **одно** значение, даже если их несколько одинаковых — [ищем минимальный модуль разности](https://ideone.com/R9sFkd).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4 

int get_array(int* array, int len, int exp) // функция
{
    int min = abs(array[0]-exp), val = array[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (min > abs(array[i]-exp))
        {
            min = abs(array[i]-exp);
            val = array[i];
        }
    }
    return val;
}

int main() // тестирующая программа
{
    int array[N];
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%i]=", i);
        scanf("%i", &array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
    s = get_array(array, N, -10);
    printf("\n\ns = %d\n\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Если надо выводить все — складируем их в массив, сортируем, выводим все с одинаковым минимальным значением модуля разности. Или делаем второй проход и, зная минимальное значение, заново проверяем все элементы массива и выводим нужные, для которых эта разность соответствует минимальной.

**Update**

Мне казалось, что как выводить все значения, я расписал, и написать соответствующий код — дело 5 минут. Оказалось, надо не только разжевать, но и проглотить... Глотаю:

```
void get_array(int* array, int len, int exp) // функция
{
    int min = abs(array[0]-exp);
    for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (min > abs(array[i]-exp))
        {
            min = abs(array[i]-exp);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (min == abs(array[i]-exp))
            printf("A[%d] = %d  ",i,array[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main() // тестирующая программа
{
    int array[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%i]=", i);
        scanf("%i", &array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
    get_array(array, N, -10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Но мне нужно выводить все ближайшие значения к exp. Если массив `5 0 -9 -11` или `5 0 -9 -10` , то нужно вывести -9 и -11 или -9 -10 соответственно. Так же, если `-10 -10 -10 0` , то выводится -10. А вот если `-10 -10 -9 0` , то выводит только -10. Потому что алгоритм должен выводить самый близкие к exp числа. Очень крутое объяснение и метод, но я не разобрался до конца, как докачать код, что выводить все ближайшие.

Comment: Насколько "ближайшие"? Ведь *если 5 0 -9 -10 , то нужно вывести -9 -10* — почему? Если есть *точное* совпадение? Словом, без **точного, однозначного и полного** текста задания дать точный, однозначный и полный ответ невозможно — он поневоле будет нести в себе додуманное отвечающим условие. Если вас все еще интересует ответ на ваш вопрос — задайте его правильно и полно...

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, ошибка! Если 5 0 -9 -10 , то нужно вывести только -10, потому что -10 ближе к -10, чем -9. Весь текст задания в названии вопроса. Оно близко к абстрактному, но как именно должен работать алгоритм, я объяснил в теме вопроса. Так как вывести все ближайшие?

Comment: Вы пишете *Весь текст задания в названии вопроса*. Я на это и ориентировался: *Написать функцию нахождения в массиве целых чисел **элемента, ближайшего** к значению второго аргумента типа int*. Не "элементов, ближайших"! Вы получили ответ в точности на заданный вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Определите расстояние между числами:

```
int dist(int a, int b) {
    // return abs(a - b);
    if (a <= b) {
        return b - a;
    }
    return a - b;
}
```

Вычислите минимальное расстояние до элемента массива:

```
int min_dist(int target, int n, const int array[/* n */]) {
    int min_d = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        const int d = dist(target, array[i]);
        if (d < min_d) {
            min_d = d;
        }
    }
    return min_d;
}
```

Распечатайте все числа на минимальном расстоянии:

```
void print_nearests(int target, int n, const int array[/* n */]) {
    const int min_d = min_dist(target, n, array);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (dist(target, array[i]) == min_d) {
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Протестируйте:

```
int main() {
    {
        const int array[] = {0, 2, -9, -11};
        // -9 -11
        print_nearests(-10, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), array);
    }
    {
        const int array[] = {0, 2, -9, -12};
        // -9
        print_nearests(-10, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), array);
    }
    {
        const int array[] = {-9, -11, -9, 10};
        // -9 -11 -9 
        print_nearests(-10, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), array);
    }
    {
        const int array[] = {10, -10, -10, -10, 10};
        // -10 -10 -10
        print_nearests(-10, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно хорошо продумать алгоритм. Вот несколько мыслей:

1. Не нужно запоминать найденные элементы массива, так как их значения легко получить из тренировочного числа и найденной наименьшей разницы (это небольшая оптимизация).
2. В цикле нужно хранить модуль наименьшей найденной разницы и два логических признака: найдено меньшее, найдено большее.
3. Если найдена разница 0, то можно выйти из цикла.

Comment: Вы, видимо, предположили что все числа в массиве разные. Как быть с `{-10, -10, -10, -10}`?

Comment: Я предположил, что нужно найти самое ближайшее (или два самых ближайших). Это один вариант. Второй вариант - найти все самые ближайшие. В таком случае нужно сделать два прохода: в первом найти наименьшую разницу, во втором вывести ближайшие числа.

Comment: Первый вариант соотвествует тому, что выделено жирным в вопросе

Comment: Тогда для массива `{-9, -9, -9, 0}` надо выводить `-9 -9`? Боюсь у ТС легкая путаница в голове. Формулировка "два ближайших" выглядит очень подозрительно.

Comment: Два ближайших к -10 это -9 и -11!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  Если `-10, -10, -10, -10` , то ближайший будет -10

Comment: @rotabor Нужно найти все ближайшие. Почти всегда будет одно ближайшее. Два будет в случае, если оба числа равноудалены от exp, в нашем примере это -9 и -11. Если